# How do I access my configuration from within a static function in .Net Core 2.1?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-2.1

I am creating an Azure web job in .Net Core 2.1 (via a "console" app in Visual Studio). In this project, I have a static function that reads messages from a queue. Within this function, I need to use connection strings (from my configuration) to write to a database. This is my setup:

**Program.cs**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new HostBuilder();
        builder.ConfigureWebJobs(b =>
        {
            b.AddAzureStorageCoreServices();
            b.AddAzureStorage();
        });
        builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, config) =>
        {
            var conf = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true).Build();
            config.AddConfiguration(conf);
            config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
        })
        builder.ConfigureLogging((context, b) =>
        {
            b.AddConsole();
        });
        var host = builder.Build();
        using (host)
        {
            host.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

**Functions.cs**

```
public class Functions
{
    public static void ProcessQueueMessage([QueueTrigger("myqueue")] string message, ILogger logger, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        logger.LogInformation(message);
        logger.LogInformation(configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDatabase"));
    }
}
```

**appsettings.json**

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MyDatabase": "foo",
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "foo2",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "foo3"
  }
}
```

However, when I run this, I get the following error:

> **Error indexing method 'Functions.ProcessQueueMessage'**
>
> Cannot bind parameter 'configuration' to type IConfiguration. Make
>   sure the parameter Type is supported by the binding. If you're using
>   binding extensions (e.g. Azure Storage, ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make
>   sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in
>   your startup code (e.g. builder.AddAzureStorage(),
>   builder.AddServiceBus(), builder.AddTimers(), etc.).

I am very new to .Net Core, especially the DI pattern. And I believe that is the issue. I also see many examples of how to implement and use the configuration from within the `Main` function, but not from within a static helper function like this. How do I properly implement my configuration from within my static function?

Comment: Is this WebJobs or Azure Functions?

Comment: It is a WebJob.

Comment: Not something I have a lot of experience with, but inside `ConfigureWebJobs` can you do `b.Services.AddConfiguration()` or even `b.Services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration, Configuration>()`?

Comment: Unfortunately that does not fix it. That's a good thought, though. I was thinking I needed something like that. But unfortunately I get the same error.

Comment: Well that was only part of it! Can you now inject `IConfiguration` into the `Functions` class as a constructor parameter, e.g. `public Functions(IConfiguration configuration) {...}`

Comment: I'll try that when I get back (about to hit the road). But - would that make a difference being that `ProcessQueueMessage` is a **static** function?

Comment: Well make it not static!

Comment: @MattSpinks Curious. Why initialize a new configuration builder when the delegate parameter is already a configuration builder just to add the built `conf` to the `config`?

Comment: The reason is that I don't fully understand the DI pattern as it relates to a WebJob in .Net Core. And I am struggling to find some documentation on it. This example uses a similar pattern for the logger, so why would the same kind of pattern NOT work for the configuration? At least that was my thinking when I added it. In other words, I don't fully understand what I am doing here.

Answer (score 3):

Consider changing the approach and not try to inject `IConfiguration`.

Create a class to hold your desired settings

```
public class MyOptions {
    public string MyDatabase { get; set; }
}
```

Refactor the setup to also use `ConfigureServices` and extract the desired configuration to populate the settings object and add it to the service collection

```
var builder = new HostBuilder();
builder
    .ConfigureWebJobs(b => {
        b.AddAzureStorageCoreServices();
        b.AddAzureStorage();
    })
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration(config => { //not using context so no need for it really
        config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true).Build();
        config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
    })
    //...ADDITION HERE
    .ConfigureServices((context, services) => {
        //Configuration should be available by now, so access what you need.
        var connectionString = context.Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDatabase");
        //If null you have the option to fail early, otherwise carry on.
        var myOptions = new MyOptions {
            MyDatabase = connectionString,
        };
        services.AddSingleton(myOptions);
    }
    .ConfigureLogging((context, b) => {
        b.AddConsole();
    });

//...
```

That way at this point you should be able to add your object as a dependency to the function

```
public class Functions {
    public static void ProcessQueueMessage(
        [QueueTrigger("myqueue")] string message, 
        ILogger logger, 
        MyOptions options) {
        logger.LogInformation(message);
        logger.LogInformation(options.MyDatabase);
    }
}
```

I personally believe trying to access `IConfiguration` outside of startup to be more trouble than its worth and would even rank it with service locator anti-pattern and injecting `IServiceProvider`. Get what you need from it during setup, register that with service collection so it's available for injection where needed explicitly.

Comment: Thanks Nkosi, I'm going to give this a shot. I am wondering, though, is this uncommon? Surely I can't be the only one trying to get my configuration properties from within a helper function in a .Net Core WebJob. Yet I can't seem to find any examples of it anywhere.

Comment: For me, the lack of examples showing that are telling on their own.

Comment: Which is a concern for me. Makes me wonder if I am not approaching this right.

Comment: Hi @Nkosi, I like this approach. However, when I attempt it, I am getting the same error as before (applied to MyOptions): 

InvalidOperationException: Cannot bind parameter 'options' to type MyOptions. Make sure the parameter Type is supported by the binding. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. Azure Storage, ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. builder.AddAzureStorage(), builder.AddServiceBus(), builder.AddTimers(), etc.).

Any thoughts on that? I would like to make it work this way if possible.

Comment: @MattSpinks are you able to upgrade to v2 of azure functions? What is the current version you are using?

Comment: I'm actually using v3 of Azure.WebJobs.

Comment: @MattSpinks take a look at this then https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection#registering-services

Comment: Thanks for sending that. And I recognize that pattern. I have no problem doing it that way. It just confused me when I saw the example from Microsoft using a static function (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-how-to#triggers). I thought maybe Microsoft changed the pattern. But apparently not.

Comment: static was the original way then they moved to the instance model with DI

Comment: Well as long as I know. Just want to be sure I'm following best practices.

Comment: @Nkosi thank you so much for the guidance. I'm working with a new console app using WebJobs 3.x and trying to find config values inside the called functions. Your code above plus the guidance to use a static config class instead of adding a Singleton in the ConfigureServices sections finally got me to the point to where I can read my own values from the appconfig in the WebJob functions. This should be easier!